# Де має розташовуватися знак валют: на початку числа чи в кінці (згідно з Правописом 2019 року, ДСТУ чи іншою офіційною настановою)

Tags: правопис

Де має розташовуватися знак валют: на початку числа чи в кінці (згідно з Правописом 2019 року, ДСТУ чи іншою офіційною настановою)? Тобто правильно **$500, ₴500, €500** чи **500 $, 500 ₴, 500 €**?

Comment: Мені, здається, вам надали максимально якісну відповідь можливу у 2019 році із наявними джерелами.

Comment: @improbabl це ви про методичку харківського ХНУМГ? Це не авторитетне джерело. Потрібно дійсно авторитетне джерело (можливо про це згадує одна з настанов ДСТУ тощо).

Comment: Звичайно ні. Я цю відповідь маю на увазі https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/5876/2097.

Більш вичерпної і кращої відповіді вам ніхто не дасть, це точно.

Comment: А у тій відповіді є посилання на авторитетні джерела по українській мові - ні. Тож як ту відповідь можна прийняти? (розділ "Для інформації" не береться до уваги, бо він напряму не стосується української мови). Я чекаю на відповідь де хтось дасть посилання на ґрунтовне джерело (в Україні ж є Інститут української мови НАН України, вони ж там якісь наукові праці пишуть, мо вони шось по цьому питанню писали; також альтернативні джерела можуть бути в ДСТУ тощо)

Comment: Очевидно, не писали, бо якби писали, хтось би вже на це послався 100%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Вікіпедія](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%9E%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83#%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82)

> **Українська гривня**
>
> Згідно з настановами НБУ, оприлюдненими після прийняття знаку гривні ₴ у [2004 році](//web.archive.org/web/20070310203109/http://pr.bank.gov.ua/ukr/arhive_news.php?news_id=431&list=0), символ гривні може писатися як перед (₴500), так і після (500 ₴) номіналу. Написання символів валют в українській мові не регламентують ні ДСТУ у сфері видавничої справи, ні правопис 2019 року.
>
> На практиці символи банкнот і зокрема гривні ₴ в українській мові на письмі переважно розташовують не перед, а після грошового символу. Відповідно знак валюти гривні ₴ в українській *Вікіпедії* слід писати після суми через пропуск: 500 ₴. Не дозволяється проставити й валютний символ й валютне скорочення, має використовуватися або валютний символ, або валютне скорочення (українське скорочення, напр. *грн*, або ж міжнародне скорочення [ISO 4217](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82_(ISO_4217)), напр. *UAH*), тобто *₴ 500 млн грн* чи *UAH 500 млн ₴* — неправильно; правильно писати *500 млн ₴*, *500 млн грн* чи *500 млн UAH*.

> **Решта валют**
>
> Написання символів валют в українській мові останні настанови ДСТУ у сфері видавничої справи та найновіші правила правопису 2019 року не регламентують. На відміну від символу цента ¢, символи банкнот, зокрема долара $ та євро €, в українській мові на письмі переважно розташовують не перед, а після грошового символу.
>
> Відповідно знак валюти фунта (£), долара ($), євро (€) та інших валют в українській *Вікіпедії* слід писати після суми через пропуск: 500 £, 500 $, 500 €. Не дозволяється проставити й валютний символ й валютне скорочення, має використовуватися або валютний символ, або валютне скорочення (українське скорочення, напр. *дол*. або ж міжнародне скорочення [ISO 4217](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82_(ISO_4217)) *USD*) тобто *500 млн $ дол.* чи *500 млн $ USD* — неправильно; правильно писати *500 млн $*, *500 млн дол.* чи *500 млн USD*. Для валют різних країн, які мають однаковий валютний знак, наприклад канадського долара та американського долара, які обоє мають однаковий валютний символ ($), замість проставляння й валютного символу ($) й валютне скорочення (USD, CAD) застосуйте: *500 US$* та *500 Can$*.
>
> Знаки валют для копійок в українській мові завжди пишуться після суми: *50¢* (для американського цента) чи *50p* (для британського пенса).

> **Для всіх валют**
>
> Загалом у текстах *Вікіпедії*, де наводять багато цифрових даних, замість валютного знака краще написати назву валюти повністю; тобто *долар США*, *дол. США* чи *USD* або *гривень*, *грн* чи *UAH*. Це унеможливить різночитання тексту, особливо для валют, що мають однакові символи валют (напр. *$*).

Зауважу, же то окремі правила Вікіпедії, котрі можуть змінюватися з часом або мати свої питання, наприклад особисто мені не зрозуміло з якого стандарта скорочення *Can* в *Can$*.

Comment: Зазначу, що те, що Ви цитуєте, це не **стаття**, а фрагмент **внутрішніх** настанов Вікіпедії (причому ще не ухвалених, проект). Але, звісно, Вікіпедія **має великий вплив**, тож якщо вони самі ретельно слідуватимуть цьому проекту, то, можливо, так воно й стане. (Хоча «$500 USD» мені особисто ріже очі — як на мене: або вже «USD $500», як у світі пишуть «US$ 500», «R$500» тощо, або вже обидві позначки після числа — якщо допускати одночасне використання декількох позначок узагалі.)

Comment: Update: І цей фрагмент проекту [був змінений вчора](https://uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Вікіпедія:Оформлення_тексту&type=revision&diff=26052983&oldid=25008055&diffmode=source) тим самим Piznajko. А попереднє формулювання було: **«Знаки валют пишуться після суми й відбиваються від неї нерозривним пробілом: 500 $ (`500&nbsp;$`), а не $500 чи 500$»** (щоправда теж без джерела).

Comment: @piznajko і Sasha, а я, до речі, не впевнений щодо того, чи кожну правку Вікіпедії треба вносити в якості правок до дописів на цьому сайті.

Comment: @bytebuster кожну правку дійсно нема сенсу вносити. Але цю конкретну будь ласка схввли, бо там роз'яснення щодо використання одночасно ₴ та UAH

Answer (score 12):

#### Як писати нам

[Новий правопис 2019](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf) не фіксує цього.

Однак я не бачу історичних передумов писати знак грошової одиниці у якомусь іншому місці, окрім як після числа — ми завжди писали назву одиниці після числа, зокрема:

- для інших типів одиниць (не грошових): «50 метрів», «30 кілограмів», «10 осіб»;
- для скорочень інших типів одиниць (не грошових): «50 м», «30 кг», «10 ос.»;
- для грошових одиниць: «100 гривень», «15 доларів», «40 копійок»;
- для скорочень грошових одиниць: «100 грн», «15 дол.», «40 коп.».

Тобто я не кажу, що писати знак грошової одиниці перед числом буде неправильно — але, на мою думку, це вже буде створення нової традиції (можливо, наслідуючи, як американці пишуть «$»).

#### Для інформації: як пишуть знаки грошових одиниць у світі

Це залежить від двох речей:

- який саме знак грошової одиниці (наприклад, американці пишуть знак долара до — «$1», а знак цента — після — «1¢»);
- від мови й народу (наприклад, знак долара американці пишуть до — «$1», а франкомовні канадці — після — «1$»).

Щодо найвідоміших у нас знаків валют:

- Знак долара («$») пишуть:

  - до числа, наприклад «$12.99», — найчастіше (при цьому, коли треба зазначити різновид долара, адже існує не лише американський долар, зазвичай пишуть так: «US$12.99»);
  - після числа з нерозривним пробілом, наприклад «12,99 $», — канадці в текстах французькою (принаймні так каже [лінгвістична рекомендація «American dollar (symbol)» від «Translation Bureau» під егідою уряду Канади](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_a&page=9IYDvHKNiH6Q.html); коли треба зазначити різновид долара, пишуть «12,99 $ US», де обидва пробіли нерозривні);
  - посередині числа замість розділювача між цілою й дробовою частиною, наприклад «12$99» чи «12 $ 999», — португальці стосовно португальського ескудо (колишня грошова одиниця, що теж позначалася як «$») і кабовердійці стосовно кабовердійського ескудо (чинна грошова одиниця, що теж позначається як «$»).
- Знак євро («€») [«Interinstitutional style guide» від «Publications Office of the European Union»](http://publications.europa.eu/code/en/en-370303.htm#position) каже писати:

  - до числа без пробілу («€30») — у текстах англійською, нідерландською, ірландською і мальтійською;
  - після числа з нерозривним пробілом («30 €») — у текстах іншими мовами (зокрема французькою, [латвійською](https://mrserge.lv/2014/pareizrakstibas-nodarbibas-8-eiro-simbola-pareiza-rakstisana-otra-dala/) тощо).

  Наскільки я розумію, правила написання знаку цей документ встановлює відповідно до традицій, які мали відповідні мови чи народи для попередніх валют.

Цікаво, що [ISO-4247-коди](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82_(ISO_4217)) найчастіше пишуть дещо подібно до знаків валют у відповідних мовах, зокрема:

- вищенаведена лінгвістична рекомендація «American dollar (symbol)» від «Translation Bureau» каже писати «USD 12.99» у текстах англійською і «12,99 USD» у текстах французькою (в обох випадках пробіл нерозривний);
- вищенаведений «Interinstitutional style guide» від «Publications Office of the European Union» каже писати «EUR 30» у текстах англійською, ірландською і мальтійською та «30 EUR» у текстах іншими мовами (в обох випадках пробіл нерозривний). Зазначу, що для нідерландської мови (якщо це не помилка в якомусь із документів) усе ж позиція знака євро й ISO-4247-коду відрізняються: «€30», але «30 EUR».

Див. також: внутрішні обговорення про стиль написання цін і знаків валют на travel.meta.stackexchange.com: [1](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/628), [2](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3734).

Comment: Хто поставив «мінус» — можете, будь ласка, аргументувати?

Comment: Як не дивно, не я. :) Можливо, комусь здалася зайвою друга частина допису, бо вона не стосується української?

Comment: Щодо долара є ще стаття від Translation Bureau
https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_a&page=9IYDvHKNiH6Q.html

І ще є такий пов'язаний тред на Meta Travel 
https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3737/101239

Можете додати в джерела і доповнити інформацією звідти.

Comment: @improbable, наче додав.

Answer (score 3):

Правопис цього не регламентує, тому це питання стилістики. Різні стилістичні порадники (зокрема, різних видань, таких як Вікіпедія) можуть давати протилежні настанови та рекомендації.

Ось одна з них:

> *Знаки валюти (долар, гривня)*
>
> Знак долара, як і знаки інших валют, пишеться після суми й відбивається від неї нерозривним пробілом: 500 $, а не $500 чи 500$. Однак у тексті значок валюти рекомендовано замінювати словесним позначенням, наприклад 100 дол.
>
> У текстах, де наводять багато цифрових даних, що означають кошти, слово «гривень» зазвичай пишуть скорочено — грн, крім випадків, коли це слово стоїть наприкінці абзацу. Суму грошей більше ніж одна тисяча в текстах рекомендовано писати так: 5 тис. грн або 5 тис. гривень; 1,5 млн грн або 1,5 млн гривень; 2,5 млрд грн або 2,5 млрд гривень.

[Джерело](http://eprints.kname.edu.ua/46513/1/31-10-17-%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%20%D1%89%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%A5%D0%9D%D0%A3%D0%9C%D0%93-%D0%A0%D0%92%D0%92.pdf):

Загальні вимоги до підготовки, оформлення та видання наукової і навчально-методичної літератури : метод. рекомендації / Харків. нац. ун-т
міськ. госп-ва ім. О. М. Бекетова ; уклад. О. В. Михаленко. — зі змін. та доп. — Харків : ХНУМГ ім. О. М. Бекетова, 2017. — 66 с.

Answer (score 3):

[Згідно з настанов НБУ](https://web.archive.org/web/20070310203109/http://pr.bank.gov.ua/ukr/arhive_news.php?news_id=431&list=0) оприлюдненими після прийняття знаку гривні ₴ у 2004 році символ гривні може писатися як перед (₴500), так і після (500 ₴) номіналу. Не заважаючи на заяву НБУ у 2004 році, станом на 2019 рік написання символів валют в українській мові останні настанови [ДСТУ у сфері видавничої справи](http://web.archive.org/web/20190906235739/http://www.ukrbook.net/vidavc.html) та найновіші [правила правопису 2019 року](http://web.archive.org/web/20190921190642/https://www.ulif.org.ua/system/files/pravopus_ua_05.06.pdf) не регламентують.

На практиці, в україномовних ЗМІ та на сайті НБУ, на відміну від символу центу ¢, символи банкнот й зокрема гривні (₴), фунту (£), долару ($), та євро (€) в українській мові на письмі зазвичай розташовують не після, **а перед грошовим символом**.