# Як писати знак долара - до чи після числа?

Tags: пунктуація

До чи після числа?
$ 100 – 100 $
Правопис не регулює це питання, в текстах трапляється по-різному. Але на що орієнтуватися?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Де має розташовуватися знак валют: на початку числа чи в кінці (згідно з Правописом 2019 року, ДСТУ чи іншою офіційною настановою)](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/5877/585)

Comment: Відповіді там нема, але дякую))

Answer (score 1):

Написання **символів валют** в українській мові найновіші правила [правопису 2019 року](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf) не регламентують. Як зручно, так і вказуєте "1000 ₴" або "$29 048.71 млрд." Класифікація валют ([ISO 4217](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82_(ISO_4217))).

Розташування знака валюти і тип роздільника ([на прикладі євро](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82)): **3,14 €**, **€3.14**.